# Drupal : adding status field to node

Tags: drupal, permissions, content-management-system, cck

What's the best way to create in Node additional **status** field that is a list of fixed string values, and is visible to users, but modifiable by admins only?
I am limited to Drupal 5, but interested in Drupal 6 solutions too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [CCK Field Permissions module](http://drupal.org/project/cck_field_perms) to lock users out of editing specific CCK fields - you'd just need to create a CCK text field with a select box widget, then allow users to view but not edit it. In Drupal 6, this comes with CCK itself.